# Taylor Expansion of algebraic equivalent equation yields different results

Tags: taylor-expansion, solution-verification

I am applying the perturbation method to find an approximate solution. However, I don't think that this information is of importance to this question. It's more an algebraic question.

**I have the following equation:**

$$\frac{1}{(p-\delta)^4}+ a  +c(p-\delta)=0\tag{1}$$

$\delta$ is a small variation (perturbation) around a known point $p$. A truncated first order Taylor expansion approximation yields:

$$a+\delta \left(\frac{4}{p^5}-c\right)+c p+\frac{1}{p^4}\tag{2}=0$$

Now, I could have started a bit differently:
I could have multiplied both sides of equation 1 by $(p-\delta)^4$ without changing its meaning. I do this to emphasis that it is a quintic equation:

$$c (p-\delta)^5+a (p-\delta)^4+1 \tag{3}=0$$

However, now, when I do the truncated first order Taylor expansion approximation, I get:

$$\delta \left(-4 a p^3-5 c p^4\right)+a p^4+c p^5+1=0 \tag{4}$$

This is not the same result as before, although eq. 1 and 3 yield the same solution.

This is evident, if I solve both equation 2 and equation 4 for $\delta$:

From Equation 2, I get:

$$\delta = \frac{p \left(c p^5+a p^4+1\right)}{c p^5-4} \tag{5}$$

From Equation 4, I get:

$$\delta = \frac{c p^5+a p^4+1}{p^3 (4 a+5 c p)}\tag{6}$$

Assigning numeric values ($\{a\to 1,c\to 1,p\to 1\}$):

- Equation 5 yields
  $$\delta = -1$$
- Equation 6 yields
  $$\delta = \frac{1}{3}$$

**To me both equation 1 and equation 3 are the same, hence the final $\delta$ should be the same too.** I don't quite understand what I did wrong, and would highly appreciate your help.

EDIT:
Maybe in other words: **If eq.1 and eq.3 are the same, then shouldn't their Taylor expansion be the same too?** The thing is: At the end I am interested in how much the perturbation $\delta$ changes the known exact solution(of a simpler system) $p$. However, it seems that depending on which equation (1 or 3) I take, I end up with a different perturbation $\delta$. As this calculation is done for a real physical system, I need to be sure about the perturbation to predict failure modes. Hence, I would be very glad, if you could help me spot my thinking mistake.

For those of you, who like to work with *Mathamatica*:

```
Solve[Normal[
   Series[1/(p - \[Delta])^4 + a + c*(p - \[Delta]), {\[Delta], 0, 
     1}]] == 0, \[Delta]]

Solve [Normal[
   Series[1 + a*(p - \[Delta])^4 + c*(p - \[Delta])^5, {\[Delta], 0, 
     1}]] == 0, \[Delta]]
```

[image]

Comment: @Somos Thanks for your comment. Would you agree that eq. 1 and eq.3 are the same ?

Comment: @Somos Okay, but I still don't understand it. If eq.1 and eq.3 are the same, then shouldn't their Taylor expansion be the same too? This is were I am stuck...

Comment: @Somos Thanks for spotting the typo, but unfortunate this was only a copy error. Please see the edit. I added the Mathematica output and you can clearly see the difference.

Comment: You have expanded $f(p-\delta)$ and $f(p-\delta)(p-\delta)^4$, of course you'll not get the same expansions: to get your the LHS of (4) you'll need to multiply LHS of (2) by $(p-\delta)^4$ (or just $p^4-4p^3\delta$) and omit the higher order terms. [You're confusing yourself by all these $=0$'s I think.]

Comment: @ancientmathematician Many thanks for your answer. I am not sure that I understand it though. Multiplying equation 1 by  (p−δ)^4  should not change its result ?

Comment: I wish you wouldn't say "equation". You are expanding the LHS of each and these are *not the same*. Here's an equation: $\delta=0$; first order terms, $\delta$. Multiply the equation by $\delta$ and get $\delta^2=0$; first order terms, $0$. You can't multiply a function by powers of $(p-\delta)$ and leave the Taylor expansion unchanged.

Comment: @ancientmathematician If you have the time, would you mind adding a little example as an answer ? Maybe you could add a plot to show the difference ? This would be very helpful. I would really like to understand how much I can manipulate the left hand and right hand side of an equation before doing a Taylor Expansion.

Comment: You have said "equation" yet again. *There is no such thing as the Taylor expansion of an equation!* If you have a (nice) function (or expression) you can get a Taylor expansion; if you start multiplying it by other things then the function you get will almost certainly have a different Taylor expansion. Anything I could add would distract you from this key point.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Okay, I think that I slowly begin to understand my issue. Thank you for your patience. So, in essence by multiplying the LHT of equation 1 by (p−δ)^4 I created a new LHT (a new function), which of course has a different Taylor expansion. Okay, I can accept that. Then the remaining issue that I have is. By construction both functions should yield the same δ, if I set them equal to zero, right ? So my question is, why would this not be the case for the respective Taylor expansions when I set them equal to zero ?

Comment: Why should they provide the same $\delta$? If you look at my first comment you will see how to reconcile the first order terms of your two expansions. Have you carried out the multiplication and seen that they are now the same?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(\delta) = \frac{1}{(p-\delta)^4} + a + c(p-\delta)$.
Assume that $p\ne 0$.

You want to solve the equation $f(\delta) = 0$.

Method 1: You solve $f(0) + f'(0) \delta = 0$.

Method 2: You solve $g(0) + g'(0) \delta = 0$ where $g(\delta) = f(\delta)(p-\delta)^4$.

Note that $g(0) = f(0)p^4$ and $g'(0) = f'(0)p^4 - 4p^3f(0)$.

Thus, in Method 2, you actually solve $f(0)p^4 + (f'(0)p^4 - 4p^3f(0))\delta = 0$,
or $f(0) + f'(0)\delta - \frac{4}{p}f(0)\delta = 0$.

Unless $f(0) = 0$, the solutions in Method 1 and Method 2 are different.